# infinite sequence of sets $\{X_i\}$ that for each $i$, $X_i\in X_{i-1}$

Tags: set-theory

I need to show that the following infinite sequence $\{X_i\}$ doesn't exist: 
for all $i$, $X_i \in X_{i-1}$

I really don't know where to start. The only thing in my mind is the axiom : for every non empty set $X$ exists $Y \in X$ s.t $X\cap Y=\emptyset$. But I'm not sure if it is indeed helpful and how can I use it here.

Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify: is each $X_i$ a set? If so, do you mean $X_i\in X_{i-1}$ or $X_i\subseteq X_{i-1}$?

Comment: yes, X_i is a set for all i (see the title). 
The first option you suggested is the correct one, X_i in X_(i-1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll assume that $i\in \omega$ in your question.

Let $X=\{X_i : i\in \omega\}$ (you'll need to check this is indeed a set).

By the foundation axiom, which you stated, there exists a set $Y\in X$ such that $X\cap Y=\emptyset$. Therefore $Y=X_i$, for some $i\in \omega$.

We have, on the one hand, $X_{i+1}\in X_i = Y$. And on the other hand $X_{i+1}\in X$.

It follows that $X_{i+1}\in X\cap Y=\emptyset$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: When it’s a homework question, a good hint is really more appropriate when it’s possible to give one.

Comment: I myself ask stuff here, I only come here as a last resort and, personally, I'm fed up with the half-ass answers I get which lead me nowhere. So I'm not gonna do the same to other people.

Having said that, I do see where you're coming from and your answer to the question has just the right ammount of information. But considering what I said above, I just couldn't do it like that.

Comment: Really? Your user page shows only one question, with an answer that you accepted with thanks.

Comment: If you know what cookies are, then you'll understand why there's only one question. 

If you don't, then trust me.

Comment: And please, accept my apologies if I was rude. I actually blame myself for not being able to promplty understand the answers I get. However it seems that people who give answers don't understand how difficult it is for us to follow.

Comment: That’s okay. I was just mildly frustrated, since I’d deliberately left the last bit undone. As for answers in general, I agree that one sees a very wide variety here. I do try to adjust mine to the apparent level of the question, but I also expect the OP to comment on my answer with further questions if necessary, in which case I’ll expand. Others prefer to give only complete answers. *shrug*

Comment: Well anyway thanks to both of you, it's much easier than I had thought

Answer (score 5):

HINT: This follows from the [axiom of regularity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity) and the [axiom schema of replacement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_replacement). Replacement allows you to define the set $\mathscr{X}=\{X_n:n\in\omega\}$. Regularity then says that there is an $X\in\mathscr{X}$ such that $X\cap\mathscr{X}=\varnothing$. Can you see how to finish it from here? If not, I’ve finished it in the spoiler-protected bit below; mouse-over to see it.

> Clearly $X=X_n$ for some $n\in\omega$, but then $X_{n+1}\in X_n\cap\mathscr{X}$, and we have a contradiction.